# How secure is the iPhone's temporary file directory?

Tags: ios, swift, security, temporary-files

On my app (swift 2.3, xcode 7+, for iOS 9+) I'm write to a file, use the file, and then delete the file from a tmp directory created with `NSTemporaryDirectory` (on the app sandboxed). Although its a quick automated sequence, for a brief moment the file is written to the tmp directory in order to be used and then deleted.

My concern is: How secure, for that brief moment, is the file stored at tmp directory? Could an attacker get access to the file at the moment it's on the tmp directory?

Comment: Turn ON data protection and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a file just to delete it, you should try to avoid storing the file on the system altogether. If you absolutely have to store the data on the device, you can use the [`.completeFileProtection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/writingoptions/1617198-completefileprotection) option.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files), `.completeFileProtection` will make it so the file is accessible only when the device is unlocked. This means that the only way that someone would have access to your data is if they have your phone's password, are somehow able to remotely unlock it using said password, and then execute code that has access to your app's sandboxed temporary file storage.

As far as I know, this would be very hard to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

Every sandboxed app on iOS or macOS has an own temporary directory that no other app has any access to. `NSTemporaryDirectory()` returns a private temporary folder specific to your app only. An attacker cannot access that file, unless the iPhone is jailbroken and if the iPhone is jailbroken an attacker can pretty much directly patch your app code or replace the system kernel or do whatever else he likes to do (e.g. running your app in a debugger and make it dump the content of all file write operations to console, so no matter what you do, you cannot avoid him seeing the file content).

Also the iPhone storage is always encrypted, so even if someone would cut off battery power after a file was written and then try to directly read data from the flash chips, that data will be encrypted and totally useless. To access the flash storage, you need the master key from the secure enclave and that key can only be accessed with the unlock PIN/password of the device and once unlocked, it can also be access it with Touch ID or Face ID, when enabled, until the device is rebooted or put into emergency mode (but only for a limited amount of time before the device locks itself up and requires you to re-enter the PIN/password).